# C++ ostringstream.str().c_str()

Tags: c++, string

I want to open file as binary and load to const char*.

Everything is OK until c_str()

```
ifstream t("movie.mp4", ios::binary);
ostringstream file_string_o;
file_string_o << t.rdbuf();
string file_string = file_string_o.str();
```

Here is problem when I use c_str():

```
std::cout << file_string << std::endl;// output: QEQEQEQEQEQEQEQEQEQE� etc..

std::cout << file_string.c_str() << std::endl;//output ���
```

It returns my only for 3 bytes. Why?

Thanks

Comment: What do you think `c_str()` does?

Comment: You are trying to interpret a binary file as a C string, how is that supposed to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't `c_str()` that's the issue.

[std::string::c_str() returns all the data the string represents.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)

The problem is that the overloaded `operator <<` for `const char *` stops at the first `0` byte encountered. In other words, it is `operator <<` preventing you from getting all the data.

To alleviate this, you can use `cout` like this:

```
std::cout.write(file_string.c_str(), file_string.size());
cout << std::endl;
```

The `write()` member function takes a pointer to a buffer and the number of bytes to write starting at that pointer.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks.  I was editing my answer, but you beat me to it.